# Set-GPLink : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Target'. The argument is null or empty

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get this powershell code to work, but to no avail. I get the following error:

```
Set-GPLink : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Target'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

Here's the code :

```
 function gpo_order([string]$nom_gpo,[string]$nom_ou,[int]$nombre)

    {
        if ($nom_gpo.TEXT -eq "")
    {
 $erreur.Text = "Vous devez entrer un nom de gpo"
 }

Elseif ($nom_ou.TEXT -eq "")
 {
    $erreur.Text = "Vous devez entrer un nom de OU sous la forme 'ou=Bureautique,ou=Desjardins,dc=mvt,dc=desjardins,dc=com'"
 }

Elseif ($gpo_rang.TEXT -eq "") 
{
$erreur.Text = "Vous devez entrer un numéro de rang pour la gpo"
}

else
{
****Set-GPLink -Name $nom_gpo -Target $nom_ou -Order $nombre****

  
}
}
```

I cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: welcome to SO. Apparently $nom_ou is empty, try printing it out to see if it is indeed not-empty.

Comment: Show us how you call rhe function and especially what you are sending to parameter `$nom_ou`

Comment: Here's how i call the functions : 
$Bouton_gpo_ordre.Add_Click({ $erreur.text = "" ;gpo_order($nom_gpo.Text,$nom_ou.Text,$gpo_rang.Text) })

Comment: Here's the TextBox code :

$nom_ou                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$nom_ou.multiline               = $True
$nom_ou.text                    = ""
$nom_ou.width                   = 228
$nom_ou.height                  = 20
$nom_ou.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(250,150)
$nom_ou.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

Comment: Remove the brackets when calling a function. PowerShell uses **space** characters on function parameters: `gpo_order($nom_gpo.Text,$nom_ou.Text,$gpo_rang.Text)` --> `gpo_order $nom_gpo.Text $nom_ou.Text $gpo_rang.Text)`